# AWS Kinesis Firehose in us-west, but output S3 bucket in us-east

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I created Kinesis Firehose stream in **eu-west** region in order to publish records to it from **eu-west** SQS. 
I need my Kinesis Firehose stream to deliver those records to S3 bucket, that is in **us-east**. I know that I can specify output bucket from any region for Kinesis Firehose. However, I am not sure what would be latency impact if I do so?

Note: I definitely can create S3 bucket in the same region as my Firehose stream. However, publishing data to us-east bucket would make my further analysis much easier.

Comment: If it lets you store the output in a bucket in the other region, then just do it. The latency would be minor and you are unlikely to be using the data immediately anyway (or are you?).

Comment: YEap, I tried with test data and I am able to send the data from Firehose in EU to S3 bucket in US.  Yes, I don't use the data immediately. Thank you!

Comment: any additional cost for the cross region? who is paying for digestion?